# Fork Program Output

Tags: c, process, fork

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        fork();
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I am a little confused on the way fork works, to my understanding fork duplicates the memory including the stack, heap, static data, and text.  I thought the program would return:
0
0
1
1
1
1
But I compiled and ran the program and the output is as follows:
0
1
0
1
1
1
Why is this?

Comment: what? the order of course is undetermined since they are from different processes.

Comment: You should put a `fflush(NULL);` just before your `fork();` and you should always test the resulf of `fork()` since it can fail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output will be random,because final answer depends on which process is finished at which time.

Answer (score 3):

`fork` returns twice *concurrently*, i.e. *at the same time*.